# Set current request route in vue-router for SRR in server-side with Node.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering

**Introduction**

I have this Node.js code from a function that handle the request/response. To explain my problem, I will use Express.js example. That piece of code is not a part of my problem but I can include to you a simple context to help you answer my question. So my code will be put in `app.get` handler, assuming `app` is an Express.js instance :

```
app.get("/", function (request, response, next) {
    // The code below could be here...
});
app.get("/test/", function (request, response, next) {
    // ...and here...
});
app.get("/*", function (request, response, next) {
    // ...and here...
});
```

- `response` is the representation of `response` I will send to the client and I will fill it with the Vue Renderer result.
- `request` contains all information about the client that execute this part of code.

**My code**

Assuming my code is running from the `/` route, the code is for example the following :

```
app.get("/", function (request, response, next) {
    var Vue = require("vue"),
        VueRouter = require("vue-router"),
        renderers = require("vue-server-renderer"),
        renderer = renderers.createRenderer();

    global.Vue = Vue;
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    stream = renderer.renderToStream(new Vue({
        template: "<div><router-view></router-view><div>",
        router: new VueRouter({
            routes: [{
                path: '/', 
                component: { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
            }, { 
                path: '/test/', 
                component: { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
            }, { 
                path: '/*', 
                component: { template: '<div>baz</div>' }
            }]
        })
    }));

    response.write("<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>");

    stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response.write(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function () {
        response.end('</body></html>');
    });
});
```

And when `response.end` is called, the content send to the client is

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div server-rendered="true"><!----></div></body></html>
```

We can see the part where the router should be display the component is `<!---->` so I guess it's because for router, no route actually match my code.

**Questions**

Why the result is not the following if no route matchs :

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div server-rendered="true"><div>baz</div></div></body></html>
```

and

How to inform my router the current url is `/` to generate this code in this case :

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div server-rendered="true"><div>foo</div></div></body></html>
```

and for exemple the following code if my current request come from `/test/`

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div server-rendered="true"><div>bar</div></div></body></html>
```

etc.

---

**Answer**

> Thanks to the answer of Ilya Borovitinov (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872542/2412797), my previous code become :

```
app.get("/", function (request, response, next) {
    var Vue = require("vue"),
        VueRouter = require("vue-router"),
        renderers = require("vue-server-renderer"),
        renderer = renderers.createRenderer(),
        router = new VueRouter({
            routes: [{
                path: '/', 
                component: { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
            }, { 
                path: '/test/', 
                component: { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
            }, { 
                path: '/*', 
                component: { template: '<div>baz</div>' }
            }]
        });

    global.Vue = Vue;
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    stream = renderer.renderToStream(new Vue({
        template: "<div><router-view></router-view><div>",
        router: router
    }));

    /* THIS IS THE SOLUTION */
    router.push(request.url);

    response.write("<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>");

    stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response.write(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function () {
        response.end('</body></html>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `vue-router` in an environment, which does not provide explicit address for the router to use. To actually force router to render proper path, you need to call `router.push(currentUrl)` for it to register.